# Game freezes when screen gets locked and unlocked

Tags: android, sleep, lockscreen

I just wrote some small game, the problem is, everytime I lock the screen during the game and unlock it after that, the game freezes. I don't know why but it happens.

Now i would like to know which method I have to change to set the game to paused or resume when the screen gets locked.

Is there any method like onScreenLocked() or onScreenWake() ?

I got three classes, the **mainactivity** that adds an **gameview** to it's own view. this gameview got a **gamethread** which keeps updating the gameview itself.

Now when onPause() gets called on the mainactivity it calls the gameView.pause(); method.

that's this method (gameview.pause()):

```
public void pause() {
    isPaused = true;
    gameThread.pause();
}
```

when the isPaused = true the game keeps updating. If not, well it doesn't.

when onResume() on the mainActivity gets called the gameView.resume(); method gets called, looking like this:

```
public void resume() {
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    gameThread.startThread();
            isPaused = false;
}
```

Yeah that's about it.
Now when pressing the home button during the game it pauses and when reentering the game it just continues where it ended up.

But when pressing the lock button, and unlock the screen after that, i just see the game frozen, i don't know why.

**I found out that the gamethread is not running anymore when unlocking the screen. I don't know how to fix it, because when adding some**

```
gameThread.start();
```

**The game will crash. 
But why does the gamethread stop working when locking the screen, but works just fine when just leaving the game and reentering it?**

EDIT:

I just found out my problem. My gameView code looks something like that:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements OnGestureListener{

public GameView(Context context, Activity activity) {
    super(context); 
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    init();
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {

        }
    });
}


public void init() {
}


public void update() {

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

}


public void pause() {
    isPaused = true;
    gameThread.setRunning(false);
}

public void resume() {
    gameThread = new GameThread(this);
    gameThread.startThread();   

}


}
```

I found out that the

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameThread.setRunning(true);
            gameThread.start();
        }
```

Just get called when pressing on home and reentering the game but **not** when locking the screen and unlocking it again. That's why the thread wouldn't start.

Now I would like to know how to call this method manually?

Comment: Add any logcat of when your game freezes. Also how do you draw? Canvas or OpenGL and how you handle pause/resume there.

Comment: No logcat! That's the strange part. Drawing on the canvas of a SurfaceView, that's what the gamethread is there for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use onPause() and onResume(). Check out the Activity life cycle for more info.

Comment: onResume() and onPause() work for me, but only when pressing the home button and getting back into the app

Comment: @user2410644 - I think we're going to need a little more information about the kind of framework you're using. Is it written in pure Android or are you using a library to take care of things?

Comment: Pure android, going to add some of the information to my original post

Comment: Then onPause should be called even when the phone is locked.